# Unable to inject module in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material2, pikaday

There is [pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) calendar plugin and i want to use it in angular 2 application.

I have installed it via `npm i pikaday` and next install types definition with `npm i @type/pikaday`, but after `import {Pikaday} from "pikaday"` i got and error:

> Module '"*/node_modules/@types/pikaday/index"' has no exported member 'Pikaday'.

But i can see in index.d.ts file from this path, that Pikaday was exported and declared. Not sure how to resolve it...

Or maybe there is some other calendar lib which is compatible with angular-material2 ? (i'm not interested in 'ng2-datepicker' and 'angular2-datepicker' and any tools with 'bootstrap' or 'jquery').

I'm use it in project generated by latest angular-cli (beta.15) and angular 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I got round this problem by adding:

`declare var Pikaday;`

after the imports in my component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I used `export default Pikaday;` instead of `export = Pikaday;` under index.d.ts file. 
Also, under the component used `import Pikaday from "pikaday"`
Added pikaday js and css file under angular-cli.json file as well. That worked for me.